# I want to open ddd. It can't open. I always receive error: Can't open display

Tags: 20.04

I tried to install ddd debugger on Ubuntu. However, I always receive the same error "Can't open display". How can I fix it?

Comment: It seems abandoned almost 10 years ago. I wouldn't expect it to work in any current distro anyway.

Comment: You haven't said what 20.04 system you're running, server? desktop?  `ddd` is "*Data Display Debugger, a graphical debugger frontend*" so has your system the required graphical capabilities?  Are you using a GUI?  using Xorg? or Wayland?

Comment: @ChanganAuto - correction: Latest release was from 2009 - so make that 13 years old.

Comment: @ArturMeinild Indeed, but the site had news up to 2013 and that was the source of my mistake.

Comment: I try to use it on my desktop. ubuntu 20.04 on a windows system.